# Linux fs: невозможность удалить файлы несмотря на наличие нужных permissions

Tags: permissions

Привет.
xDebug создает файлы трассировки и профилирования в /tmp/ с правами 664 (владелец: php-fpm, rw; группа: webdev, rw), однако я не могу их переименовать или удалить иначе как через sudo, несмотря на то, что состою в группе - шелл выдает стандартную ошибку:

> rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/cachegrind.out.5289’: Operation not permitted

в чем может быть проблема? Навряд ли у этих файлов прописывается какой-то acl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO у Вас (как и обычно у всех в Linux) у каталога `/tmp` стоит [sticky bit](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)

```
avp@avp-ubu1:templ$ ll -d /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 7 root root 4096 Jan 15 00:17 /tmp/
avp@avp-ubu1:templ$
```

и поэтому только владелец файла может его удалять (поскольку удаление файла изменяет и *сам каталог*).

Comment: в самую точку